# Pandas if-else condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am just trying on with Pandas and am not sure why I am not getting the proper output (titanic dataset from seaborn).

Status columns should show "**f**" where it says *female* in column **"sex"**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is in the assignment `data['Status'] = 'm'`. You set all values of this column to `m`. To correct this and follow your approach, you can iterate through the column using:

```
for index in range(data.shape[0]):
    if data.loc[index,'sex'] == 'male': 
        data.loc[index,'Status'] = 'm'
    else:
        data.loc[index,'Status'] = 'f'
```

There is another efficient solution using `map`:

```
val_dict= {'female': 'f', 'male': 'm'}
df['status'] = df['sex'].map(val_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

A good solution has been provided by @Phoenix based on what you have tried so far. But in the case of an if-else condition, you can use `numpy.where` function too:

```py
import numpy as np
data["Status"] = np.where(data["sex"] == "female", "f", "m")
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer a more 'pythonic' approach to solve this, with `.loc` method

```
df.loc[df['sex'] == 'female', 'status'] = 'f'  
df.loc[df['sex'] == 'male', 'status'] = 'm'
```

Another approach is with a `lamba functions`

```
df['Status'] = df['sex'].apply(lambda x: 'm' if x == 'Male' else 'f')
```

---

You should avoid ugly for-loops if possible, in fact, the reason of using Pandas DF is indeed avoiding to use for-loops etc...

If you care about performances, I believe .loc is faster.
Ciao!